# TypeError: data is not iterable , using ngfor on nested array

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

```js
  rowData=  [{
  "label": "president",
  "contestants": [{
    "name": "john key",
    "votes": 2
  }, {
    "name": "john hi",
    "votes": 1
  }, {
    "name": "john kl",
    "votes": 1
  }]
}, {
  "label": "organizer",
  "contestants": [{
    "name": "michael skie",
    "votes": 3
  }, {
    "name": "michael e",
    "votes": 1
  }]
}, {
  "label": "secretary",
  "contestants": [{
    "name": "sampson eons",
    "votes": 2
  }, {
    "name": "sampson mji",
    "votes": 2
  }]
}]
```

I have a rowData which looks like this and I want to dynamically create multiple bar charts with the results using NGFOR

```html
<div *ngIf="rowData.length >0">
  <div *ngFor="let arr of rowData  let i=index">
    <div *ngFor="let elm of arr.contestants">
   <ngx-charts-bar-vertical
    [view]="view"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [results]="elm"
    [gradient]="gradient"
    [xAxis]="showXAxis"
    [yAxis]="showYAxis"
    [legend]="showLegend"
    [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
    [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
    [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
    [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
    (select)="onSelect($event)">
  </ngx-charts-bar-vertical> 
  </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I get an error that data is not iterable. Can someone help me

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by rearranging the json

```js
rowData = [
  [{
    "label": "president",
    "contestants": [{
      "name": "john key",
      "votes": 2
    }, {
      "name": "john hi",
      "votes": 1
    }, {
      "name": "john kl",
      "votes": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "label": "organizer",
    "contestants": [{
      "name": "michael skie",
      "votes": 3
    }, {
      "name": "michael e",
      "votes": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "label": "secretary",
    "contestants": [{
      "name": "sampson eons",
      "votes": 2
    }, {
      "name": "sampson mji",
      "votes": 2
    }]
  }]
]
```

```html
<div *ngIf="rowData.length >0">
  <div *ngFor="let arr of rowData  let i=index">
    <div *ngFor="let elm of arr.contestants">
   <ngx-charts-bar-vertical
    [view]="view"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [results]="elm"
    [gradient]="gradient"
    [xAxis]="showXAxis"
    [yAxis]="showYAxis"
    [legend]="showLegend"
    [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
    [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
    [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
    [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
    (select)="onSelect($event)">
  </ngx-charts-bar-vertical> 
  </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I moved the results rowData[0]; and it solved my problem